# USA borders in JSON format

Tags: google-maps, maps

Do you know how i can find the USA borders for state/counties/cities in json format ?

Comment: http://ernestdelgado.com/elections/data_us.js http://primary-maps-2008-data.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shapes/coarse/us.js http://code.google.com/p/simile-widgets/source/browse/exhibit/trunk/src/webapp/examples/polymap/us-state-borders-coarse.json